# TouchXML Objective-C Create Document

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchxml

I'm trying to create a document with TouchXML. I followed up this tutorial https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML/blob/develop/Documentation/TouchXMLParsing.markdown to parse the XML, that's working fine. 
Now I try to generate the same XML for. I tried with

```
CXMLElement *piglet = [CXMLElement elementWithName:@"piglet" stringValue:@"1"];
CXMLElement *pigletList = [CXMLElement elementWithName:@"pigletlist"];
[pigletList addChild:piglet];
CXMLElement *name = [CXMLElement elementWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"Nifnif"];
[piglet addChild:name];
CXMLDocument *theDocument = [CXMLDocument documentWithRootElement:pigletList];
NSLog(@"document: %@", theDocument);
```

And the result is

```
<pigletlist>
  <piglet>1<name>Nifnif</name></piglet>
</pigletlist>
```

So my question: How can I create a piglet like

```
<piglet id="1">
```

I tried with

```
CXMLElement *piglet = [CXMLElement elementWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"piglet id=\"1\""]];
```

That worked fine, but not for a root element at the top, in my specific case I have an ID in my first XML-Element too and with [NSString stringWithFormat] it's placed in the closing tag too.

Thanks a lot,
matz

Comment: Id is an attribute. Use attributeForName.

Comment: attributeForName is a getter, how should I use that to set my value?